# php SimpleCassie Cassandra TimeUUID

Tags: php, cassandra

I created a column family Users using following command:

```
create column family Users with comparator=TimeUUIDType and default_validation_class=UTF8Type;
```

Then I insert a column into Users. It shows as follows.

```
RowKey: jsmith

=>(column=66829930-515b-11e0-8443-0f82b246fa40, value=hello, timestamp=1300451382)
```

I want to access it using SimpleCassie. The command is:

```
$data = $cassie->keyspace('Keyspace1')->cf('Users')->key('jsmith')->column('66829930-515b-11e0-8443-0f82b246fa40')->value();
```

(I also tried: `$data = $cassie->keyspace('Keyspace1')->cf('Users')->key('jsmith')->column($cassie->uuid('66829930-515b-11e0-8443-0f82b246fa40')->__toString())->value();`)

However, They do not work. It always return NULL.
How can I get the column value (hello) I want?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`$cassie->keyspace('Keyspace1')->cf('Users')->key('jsmith')->column($cassie->uuid('66829930-515b-11e0-8443-0f82b246fa40')->uuid)->value();)`

Cassandra expects the binary representation of a UUID, not a hex/string representation.